# Duplicated banner and side-bar in certain review queues

Tags: bug, review, design

The banner and side-bar is replicated in certain review queues:

[image]

The above image is from [this review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71236) in the Low Quality Review Queue.

Specifically, these review queues seem to be affected:

- Low Quality
- First Posts
- Late Answers

Tested on:

- Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (32-bit)
- Firefox 74.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Lots of AJAX endpoints are currently returning full pages, this goes beyond review queues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, that seems related. Since I don't have the powers you do it just showed itself in a cleaner way in review queues.